# Authorization Endpoint's Login request (POST) of Identity Server 4 ends up in bad request while made from an IFrame

Tags: identityserver4

Authorization Endpoint's Login request (POST) of Identity Server 4 ends up in bad request while made from an IFrame.

Expecting some minor tweaks to be done within the identity server that should accept the request made from iframe with certain domains.

PS: I have already added csp frame-ancestor.

I refered back to this issue with Identity Server 3. Not sure about Identity Server 4. Link: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/288